# Is this the correct way to use pause() and resume() of kafka consumer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to implement backpressure in my Kafka consumption flow using pause() and resume() APIs from Kafka Consumer Interface. My idea is to pause() consumption till the current polled messages are processed.

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        subscribe(topics);
        //noinspection InfiniteLoopStatement
        while (true) {
            final ConsumerRecords<String, Message> records = poll(Duration.of(5, ChronoUnit.SECONDS));
            if (records == null || records.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            log.info("Pausing the subscription");
            pause(this.assignment());
            log.info("Paused the subscription");
            List<CompletableFuture<Void>> completableFutureList = new ArrayList<>();
            records.forEach(record -> {
                completableFutureList.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                    try {
                        processor.read(record.value());
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                        log.error("Could not process message", e);
                    }
                }, executorService));
            });
            log.info("Waiting for completable futures to finish");
            CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutureList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
            log.info("Completable Futures finished");
            log.info("Resuming the subscription");
            commitSync();
            resume(this.assignment());
            log.info("Resumed the subscription");
        }
    }
```

From the doc [here](https://kafka.apache.org/28/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#pause(java.util.Collection)), it is said that poll() continues to be called and it will not return any records from these partitions until they have been resumed using resume(Collection). Note that this method does not affect partition subscriptions causing Partition Rebalance.

In this regard, is my implementation correct - am I blocking the poll() or poll() is taken care of by another heartbeat thread?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this? I'm thinking of using pause/resume in my consumers the same way.